# How to find a datetime that is not common between two large dataframes

Tags: r

I have two large dataframes `df1` and `df2` that theoretically should have the same number of rows since they represent the same period. They start at the same date and time and they end on the same date and time. But I found out that they differ in one-row length. I want to know exactly which row or which date is missing between one and another. As an example:

```
df1<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 06:00:00","2016-08-01 07:00:00","2016-08-01 09:00:00","2016-08-01 10:00:00","2016-08-01 11:00:00","2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 13:00:00","2016-08-01 14:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00","2016-08-01 16:00:00"),
                 Var1=c(23,34,34,56,54,34,2,34,78,65))
df1$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df1$DateTime, format ="%Y-%m-%d %H", tz = "UTC")
df2<- data.frame(DateTime=c("2016-08-01 06:00:00","2016-08-01 07:00:00","2016-08-01 08:00:00","2016-08-01 09:00:00","2016-08-01 10:00:00","2016-08-01 11:00:00","2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 13:00:00","2016-08-01 14:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00","2016-08-01 16:00:00"),
                 Var2=c(34,56,75,43,45,67,8,67,89,09,23))
df2$DateTime<- as.POSIXct(df2$DateTime, format ="%Y-%m-%d %H", tz = "UTC")

df1
              DateTime Var1
1  2016-08-01 06:00:00   23
2  2016-08-01 07:00:00   34
3  2016-08-01 09:00:00   34
4  2016-08-01 10:00:00   56
5  2016-08-01 11:00:00   54
6  2016-08-01 12:00:00   34
7  2016-08-01 13:00:00    2
8  2016-08-01 14:00:00   34
9  2016-08-01 15:00:00   78
10 2016-08-01 16:00:00   65


df2
              DateTime Var2
1  2016-08-01 06:00:00   34
2  2016-08-01 07:00:00   56
3  2016-08-01 08:00:00   75
4  2016-08-01 09:00:00   43
5  2016-08-01 10:00:00   45
6  2016-08-01 11:00:00   67
7  2016-08-01 12:00:00    8
8  2016-08-01 13:00:00   67
9  2016-08-01 14:00:00   89
10 2016-08-01 15:00:00    9
11 2016-08-01 16:00:00   23
```

I would like to find out either what is the datetime they don't share, or which row is the last one where they share the same datetime between `df1$DateTime` and `df2$DateTime`, or in which row `df1` and `df2` start to differ regarding `DateTime`. With any of these answers would be enough.

I didn't find out how to solve this with datetimes.

In this example, they don't share the date time `2016-08-01 08:00:00`. `df1` and `df2` share the same datetime for the same row until row 2, and they start to differ in datetime in row 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to spot the non-matching datetime if you use `all=TRUE`:

```
merge(df1,df2, all=TRUE)
              DateTime Var1 Var2
1  2016-08-01 06:00:00   23   34
2  2016-08-01 07:00:00   34   56
3  2016-08-01 08:00:00   NA   75
4  2016-08-01 09:00:00   34   43
5  2016-08-01 10:00:00   56   45
6  2016-08-01 11:00:00   54   67
7  2016-08-01 12:00:00   34    8
8  2016-08-01 13:00:00    2   67
9  2016-08-01 14:00:00   34   89
10 2016-08-01 15:00:00   78    9
11 2016-08-01 16:00:00   65   23
```

Could also have use the negation of `%in%` on the two datetime vectors.

```
df1$DateTime[ !df2$DateTime %in% df1$DateTime]
[1] "2016-08-01 09:00:00 UTC"
```

The first method has the advantage that you don't need to first figure out which one is shorter as well as handling the case where the non-intersection is "symmetric" in the sense that each vector has a missing value in the other. There are also some "set" functions: `setdiff`, `intersect`, and `union` but they do remove attributes and datetimes end up as numeric.

Comment: Thanks 42-!! I applied what you said but I don't still find the row. I think that the problem is, instead of that one dataframe is missing one datetime, in the data frame with one row more there is datetime repeated. Do you know how to find the two consecutive columns with the same datetime? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Two consecutive rows? If so then the `duplicated` function is available. It would not necessarily be restricted to consecutive duplications but it would definitely find consecutive duplications.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple-

**Matching-**

```
> intersect(as.character(df2$DateTime),as.character(df1$DateTime))
 [1] "2016-08-01 06:00:00" "2016-08-01 07:00:00" "2016-08-01 09:00:00" "2016-08-01 10:00:00" "2016-08-01 11:00:00" "2016-08-01 12:00:00" "2016-08-01 13:00:00"
 [8] "2016-08-01 14:00:00" "2016-08-01 15:00:00" "2016-08-01 16:00:00"
```

**Non-Matching-**

```
> setdiff(as.character(df2$DateTime),as.character(df1$DateTime))
[1] "2016-08-01 08:00:00"
```

**Note**- You can also use `%like%` from `data.table` to extract complete rows.